# Browser interpreting Javascript string as HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have the following in my source HTML:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>');</script>
    ...
</head>
```

But it is getting interpreted by my browser (Chrome) as:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    "');"
    ...
```

I've tried escaping the slash inside the `document.write` string, but that didn't work. Does anyone know how to prevent the browser from interpreting it as as a closing script tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`</script>` is alwasy interpreted as closing script tag even if it's inside string you need to split it like this:

```
'</'+'script>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape some characters in your script.

Try this:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

I escaped the `/` character with a backslash `\`, so it ends up like: `\/` in your `document.write()` statement.

For a good example of this setup, try looking at HTML5 Boilerplate project on GitHub here:

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.html#L26

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but I guess I'd have to escape the escaping backslash since I'm using Jade